# Specifying the width of a form to stop it overflowing

Tags: html, css

This is the code im working from:

http://jsfiddle.net/GCt3z/32/

It was going to be a fluid width form but it caused too many problems and incompatibility. Ive opted for a fixed width form but im confused now, because I have the form overflowing the div. Should I be specifying the width of the field wrapper or the field itself to fix this?

Comment: hi u want to this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/GCt3z/39/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working in a set div width there is no reason to work in percentages for the input field sizes. Change the input field to a fixed width. There is no reason to actually have the field wrapper that I can see. http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/GCt3z/44/

Answer (score 0):

it's overflowing, because your input field has a width of 100% + left and right border. You can set the value smaller 100%, or use the box-sizing attribute and set it to border-box.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this, is use `overflow:auto;` however, you get an anoying slidebar, but it will fit. An other way in this is just to experiment with the percentage. Set the next item `width: 99%:` I checked, your border causes the overflow.

http://jsfiddle.net/GCt3z/43/

Another way to solve it, and it is a common used thing is the use of tables, cause you can set just one table row, and the other will make it to the 100%. Not clean, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I usually specify the width of the input field so they all align, but it's your personal preference. For a textbox use:

```
input[type="text"] {
line-height:28px; width: 120px; font-family:arial, sans-serif; border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[CSS Attribute Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)